# Why redraw an thumbnail image from a file uploaded image results is blank image?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

**Behaviour expected :**

- The user upload an image.
- The user modify the thumbnail created from this image with left, right, up, down, zoom in, zoom out buttons.
- The user validate the thumbnail.

**Problem :**

After purposing a preview of the thumbnail, the result of redrawing the initial image some pixels left, right, up or down results in drawing a blank image.

**Code :**

```
function loadImage(){   
var files = document.getElementById("file_input").files;
var file = files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();
var image = new Image();

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var thumbnail_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');


if (file){
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

reader.onloadend = function(_file){
    image.src = reader.result;

    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;   
    thumbnail_canvas.width = 275;
    thumbnail_canvas.height = 275;

    var t_p_x = 0, t_p_y=0, t_d_x=275;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    thumbnail_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, t_p_x, t_p_y, t_d_x, t_d_x, 0, 0, 275, 275);

    document.getElementById('loadedImage').style.background = 'url('+canvas.toDataUrl()+')';
    document.getElementById('loadedImage').style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.getElementById('loadedImage').style.backgroundSize = image.width+"px "+image.height+"px";

    document.getElementById('preview').style.background = 'url('+thumbnail_canvas.toDataURL()+')';
    document.getElementById('preview').style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.getElementById('preview').style.backgroundSize = "275px 275px";
 }
}


  function left(){
    var t_p_x=10,t_p_y=0,t_d_x=275; 
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = document.getElementById('loadedImage').style.background.slice(4,-1);
    thumbnail_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, t_p_x, t_p_y, t_d_x, t_d_x, 0, 0, 275, 275);

    document.getElementById('preview').style.background = 'url('+thumbnail_canvas.toDataURL()+')';
    document.getElementById('preview').style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.getElementById('preview').style.backgroundSize = "275px 275px";

}
```

Any clue or experience to share about this behaviour?

Comment: What is the resulting `src`? That `.style.background.slice` seems suspect.

Comment: The result is a blank canvas. The .style.background.slice is mandatory to get the adequate parameter to set into .drawImage function. Is it cross cross origin related?